Want to Download files from Autodesk BIM360/ACC. Any sample code using Python?
Want to Download files from Autodesk BIM360/ACC. Any sample code using Python?
Download files from Autodesk BIM360/ACC. Any sample code using Python?
def download_selected_files(self):
"""Initiate download for selected files from checked folders"""
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}'}
for folder_id, checkbox in self.folder_checkboxes.items():
if checkbox.isChecked():
self.download_files_from_folder(self.project_id, folder_id, headers)

    def download_files_from_folder(self, project_id, folder_id, headers):
        """Download all Revit files from a specific folder."""
        url = f"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{project_id}/folders/{folder_id}/contents"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception if the request failed
        folder_data = response.json()
    
        # Store 'included' outside the loop if it's not part of the items in 'data'
        included_data = folder_data.get('included', [])  # Safe default if 'included' is missing
    
        for item in folder_data['data']:
            if 'displayName' in item['attributes']:
                file_name = item['attributes']['displayName']
                if file_name.endswith('.rvt'):
                    # Link the appropriate 'included' data based on item relationships
                    storage_id = item['relationships']['storage']['data']['id']
                    file_url = next((inc['attributes']['url'] for inc in included_data if inc['id'] == storage_id),
                                    None)
                    if file_url:
                        self.download_file(file_url, file_name, headers)
                    else:
                        print(f"No storage URL found for file {file_name}")


you need to get the urn of the file you want to download, then use it to obtained a collection of short lived urls to download the file in the object storage service and than use a stream to save the file locally.
    # Copyright Autodesk, Inc. 2024

import requests
import utilities  # custom module for input validation


def obtain_signed_url_download(token: str, name: str, bucket_key: str, lifespan: int = 60) -> List[str]:
    """
    https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3download-GET/
    Returns the signed url of the file
    @param token: the token with scope 'data:read'
    @param name: The source file name including extension
    @param bucket_key: the bucket key
    @param lifespan: the lifespan in seconds for the signed url
    @return: The list of signed urls
    """
    utilities.validate_string(name)  # example of input validation
    utilities.validate_string(bucket_key, 3, 128)  # example of input validation
    if not utilities.validate_int(lifespan, 2, 60):  # example of input validation
        lifespan = 60

    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    endpoint = f'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucket_key.lower()}/objects/{name}/signeds3download'
    data = {'useCdn': True, 'minutesExpiration': lifespan, 'public-resource-fallback': True}

    resp = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, json=data)    

    j = resp.json()

    urls = j.get('urls', [])
    url = j.get('url', '')
    if len(urls) > 0:
        return urls
    else:
        return [url]


def download_file_content_by_urn(urn: str) -> Any:
    """
    Uses a stream to obtain a the content in chunks
    """
    utilities.validate_string(urn)
    bk, ok = urn.split(':')[-1].split('/')
    if bk is not None and ok is not None and len(bk) > 0 and len(ok) > 0:
        signed_url = obtain_signed_url_download(ok, bk)
        if signed_url is not None and len(signed_url) > 0:
            for su in signed_url:
                with requests.get(su, stream=True) as resp:
                    yield resp.content
                    
                    
def download_file_by_urn(urn: str, output_path: str) -> bool:
    """
    Downloads a file to the specified output path starting form its OSS Urn.
    @param urn: The OSS Urn.
    @param output_path: The fully qualified path where to save the file including the extension
    @return: True if successful.
    """
    utilities.validate_string(urn)  # example of input validation
    utilities.validate_string(output_path)  # example of input validation
    res = False
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        for a in download_file_content_by_urn(urn):
            f.write(a)
        res = True
    return res


Given the Item URN 'urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.nswivt-RT5aLTADXKDbKcQ?version=2', I am trying to extract the bucket key and object key. How should I split this URN to correctly identify these two values? What might the bucket key and object key be in this case?

@vijayaadigopula, in the function 'download_file_content_by_urn()' there is what you are asking bk= bucket key, ok = object key. You need a storage urn though, what you provided is the urn of the version and that is not pointing to the bytes you need to download
